# How to span image on mulitpages in r?

Tags: r, plot

I trying to generate one plot but I need to span the image on multiple pages.

```
 pdf(file = ("Rplot%03d.pdf"), onefile=FALSE)
 height<-100
 plot(-1,-1,xlim=c(0,50),ylim=c(0,height),axes=F,ann = FALSE)

 for (i in 1:100)
 {
    rect(0, height, 10, height+.15, col="red", border = "black")
    rect(11, height, 40, height+.15, col="green", border = "black")
    rect(41, height, 50, height+.15, col="blue", border = "black")
    height<-height-1
 }

 axis(3,at=c(,0,10,20,30,40,50),cex.axis=.3,las=2)
 dev.off()
```

I want to span these rectangular plots (RGB) on multiple pdf like 10 bars per page starting with scale on each page. How can i implement it?

Page1:

```
  Scale
  rectangular bar (with three different color)
  rectangular bar (with three different color)
  .......   (7 times)
  .......
  rectangular bar (with three different color)
```

Page2:

```
  Scale
  rectangular bar (with three different color)
  rectangular bar (with three different color)
  .......   (7 times)
  .......
  rectangular bar (with three different color)
```

Page3:

```
  Scale
  rectangular bar (with three different color)
  rectangular bar (with three different color)
  .......   (7 times)
  .......
  rectangular bar (with three different color)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't; each "page" in the PDF is a separate & *complete* plot. The only way to achieve what you want is to do multiple calls to `plot()` each one using the same `ylim` and using only enough x-data to draw 10 bars. To achieve this you'll need to split the data set into chunks of 10 bars and start each plot as part of an outer `for ()` loop.